# how to spawn a background thread using Dispatcher.BeginInvoke or Dispatcher.Invoke in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, mvvm

I want to know is there a way I can spawn or start a thread using `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()`
at the same time not blocking the UI because of the thread spawned inside Dispatcher. Basically I am working on a WPF application using MVVM where at the start of this app I need to show a blank view with a textblock(with some default string) on the main window. Till here everything works. now after the view is shown I have to kick off heavy background tasks (these tasks are basically functions in my ViewModel class) and the status of these should be updated on the textblock of the view. I have bound the textblock's text property with a public property say StatusMessage in the ViewModel class. So here I go blind on these questions:

1. How and where shall I kick off the tasks? in View's code behind or in the MainView Model class? As there is no UI control on the Window I have to launch the task myself by using `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()`. by using this I am able to start the tasks but UI status doesn't get updated everytime property changes in ViewModel. I see the recent Updated status that too only when the tasks completed.
2. I have heard about BackgroundWorker class to offload the heavy tasks that are done on UI thread. here I have a doubt If I use a Dispatcher class to invoke the event which is handled by BackgroundWorker class. will it have any impact on the UI thread I mean will it be blocked or it just returns after raising the event?

some background of the application: It has a Mainwindow which just contains a logo and a MainViewModel (which has a property _viewModel) is set to datacontext of this window. This Mainwindow shows different views depending on what ViewModel is contained in _viewModel.
I am somewhat new to wpf and mvvm but this is some kind of requirement that I have to accomplish. Please advise me on this any links are welcome. thanks in advance.

Comment: `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()` does not start a Thread or Task. It just reschedules work on the main thread.

Comment: @HenkHolterman thanks for clearing the doubt regarding Dispatcher.BeginInvoke().I am able to perform the task using BackgroundWorker class and invoking it's dowork event asynchronously.